# Bootstrap 3.0 Setting absolute position for child div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i've a div block where i need to show a block always in bottom of the section no matter if above section is empty inner div should be  in the bottom   section  div like attached

[image]

this is what i am doing

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="position:relative; min-height:300px;">
  Content for upper section 

  <div class="row" style="position:absolute; bottom:0 !important;">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Div in footer  section of the parent div 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i expect even f there is no content in top section  bottom div should be in footer of the  parent div instead of starting from the top section , as in attached image but that is not the case please help me to solve  it

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://codeply.com/go/QCf98IbnAv

Comment: Yep, seems to work fine  unless there is CSS overriding this that we cannot see. Please post all of your HTML / CSS for this page in a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please try to avoid using in-line styles if you can. If you're doing it throughout your project you're only creating a lot more work for yourself in tracking down the problem or changing things later if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Check your spellings, its a typo:

Change positoin to position

Comment: its what i typed here ,  did not copy from my editor

Answer (score 0):

You must have some custom styling because i just tested your code and it works. The row-class is stuck to the bottom as it is supposed to.

By the way, all col-* classes is position relative by bootstrap default. No need to specify it in the style tag.